# Have the name of the column if my row is equal to 1 return in another one

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| index  | Q111   | Q570   | Q7891  |Info583 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1      |      1 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
| 2      |      0 |      1 |      1 |      0 |
| 3      |      0 |      0 |      0 |      1 |
| code   |      1 |      0 |      0 |      1 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I would like that for each 1 for the index rows 'code', I have the name of the corresponding column in a new column 'key_name', here is the desired final result

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| index   | Q111   | Q570   | Q7891  |Info583|key_name|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1      |      1 |      0 |      0 |      0 |  Q111  |
| 2      |      0 |      1 |      1 |      0 |  nan   |
| 3      |      0 |      0 |      0 |      1 |  nan   |
| 4      |      1 |      0 |      0 |      1 | Info583|
| code   |      1 |      0 |      0 |      1 | nan    |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Thx for any help or advices !

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
df['key_name'] = np.nan
condition = df.loc['code', :] == 1
df.loc[condition, 'key_name'] = df.columns[condition]
```

First make the column with just nan's. Then compute your condition: row with index 'code' equals 1. Then plug in the column names when condition is met.

Comment: Thx a lot, I have this error 'TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'' but I will work on it, thanks for the help